# Is there any network viewer like IE but in Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, http

If you have worked with IE you probably know there is **Developer tools** which can be access though `Tools` -> `Developer tools`. It will show you a window, by clicking on `Network` you can see something like the picture below:
[image]

Here you can see **ALL** HTTP requests (with request and response headers and body). My question is this: Is there anything like this for Firefox?

**Note:** I'm using  [Live HTTP headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)  and it's **NOT** what I want, because it doesn't show response body at all!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most famous (and the best) developing tool for Firefox is [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). You can [see all the HTTP requests and responses with Firebug](http://techbrij.com/156/view-http-requests-and-responses-with-firebug), along with many other [features](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug).

Comment: Ohh +1 for Firebug I forgot about that one.

Comment: it's awkward! I'm using Firebug for two years and didn't notice that:-D Thanks!

Comment: Firebug is such an essential developing tool. I also recommend using the [Chrome Inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), it's amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It may not be built in to Firefox, but it should do what you want plus more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). It also provide a lot of other helpful info.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best plug-in is `Fire-bug`.

Apart from that, `HTTP-Fox` Or `Fidder` you can use.